# How to use ng-scrollbar inside an angularjs selectbox?

Tags: php, css, angularjs

In my project I am using angularjs selectbox. I need to give a custom style for  selctbox scrollbar.Using ng-scrollbar I have tried but its not working

here is the reference for ng-scrollbar [click here](https://github.com/asafdav/ng-scrollbar)
which i have used

I just added a selectbox and tried but its not working

Please help me

Here is my code

```
<div ng-app="myapp">
  <div class="container" ng-controller="myctrl">

    <div class="page-header">
      <h1>ngScrollBar <small>example</small></h1>
    </div>
    Bar is shown: {{barShown}}
    <div class="well" >
      <div class="scrollme" ng-scrollbar is-bar-shown="barShown">
        <h1>Scroll me down!</h1>
        <p>...</p>
        <p>...</p>
        <p><a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" role="button" href="https://github.com/asafdav/ng-scrollbar">Learn more</a></p>
      </div>
    </div>


    <select class="scrollme" ng-options="lt.id as lt.value for lt in Value" ng-model="selectedValue" ng-change="onChange(selectedValue)">
        <option value="" >Select</option>
        </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Script

```
<script>
  var myapp = angular.module('myapp', ['ngSanitize', 'ngScrollbar']);

  myapp.controller('myctrl', function ($scope)
 {

    $scope.Value = [{ id: 1, value: '1'},{ id: 2, value: '2 - 0.76'},{ id: 3, value: '3 - 1.14'},{ id: 4, value: '4 - 1.52'},{ id: 5, value: '5 - 1.9'},
        { id: 6, value: '6 - 2.28'},{ id: 7, value: '7 - 2.66'},{ id: 8, value: '8 - 3.04'},{ id: 9, value: '9 - 3.42'},{ id: 10, value: '10 - 3.8'},
        { id: 11, value: '11 - 4.18'},{ id: 12, value: '12 - 4.56'}];

  });
</script>
```

Comment: Since you have used a working example https://github.com/asafdav/ng-scrollbar/blob/master/example/index.html everything should work. Don't ask people to fix a working code...

Comment: this is not for selectbox.I want it inside selectbox

Comment: In github they have given for page scroll bar. that is working for me. same style i have to give for selectbox scrollbar

Comment: In my code I have added a selectbox

Comment: But before asking people for help you should try to do something on your own. Now you paste/copy the code and tell people I want to have it like this. I think it's not fair asking other for help, since you didn't help yourself first. Don't want to be an ass or anything, just stating my opinion. Maybe someone will do it for you. Good luck

Comment: I have tried a lot using jquery and all But all those are not working.and I am new in angularjs.and I want this in angularjs